# Android resource linking failed due to @mipmap/ic_launcher

Tags: linker, manifest

I am facing an issue/error with the android stuido while creating ..aab signed bundle file for playstore, when i click generate signed release file , the gradle build starts and after few secs its show the error

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Ashar khokhar\EazyPosOnline\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml:66: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.expense.eazyposonline:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
C:\Users\Ashar khokhar\EazyPosOnline\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml:66: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.expense.eazyposonline:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

I have checked the ic_launcher files in the Manifest file too, there is everything alright even in manifest file the icons in the left side showing properly. Moreever when i run this application on phone it successfully complete and no such error exists , but when i try to generate Signed bundle file it is encountering an error.

Can someone please help me to get out of this....

I have checked the ic_launcher files in the Manifest file too, there is everything alright even in manifest file the icons in the left side showing properly. Moreever when i run this application on phone it successfully complete and no such error exists , but when i try to generate Signed bundle file it is encountering an error.